# changing the class of a python object (casting)

Tags: python, python-3.x

On this [python doc page](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html) it says:

> Like its identity, an object’s type is also unchangeable.

And I try this script,

```
#!python3  

class Foo:
  num = 1
  pass

class Bar:
  num = 2
  pass

f1,f2= Foo(), Foo()

f2.__class__ = Bar
print( type(f1), type(f2), f1.num, f2.num )
```

The result shows:

`<class '__main__.Foo'> <class '__main__.Bar'> 1 2`

I think I changed the `type` of `f2`.
What's wrong, What am I missing?

Comment: Python is said to be for "adults" in the sense you know what you are doing and why. The question would be: "Why would you like to change the object type?"

Comment: Just out of curiosity @pepr

Comment: This is a fair reason. Dissecting it will make you to understand better the internals. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The footnotes one that page says:

> [1]   It is possible in some cases to change an object’s type, under
>   certain controlled conditions. It generally isn’t a good idea though,
>   since it can lead to some very strange behaviour if it is handled
>   incorrectly.

If you try to change the `__class__` of f2 to `list`:

```
f2.__class__ = list
```

A TypeError raised:

```
TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types
```

Comment: Oh, didnt notice that. So I DID changed the type. thank you:)

Comment: @dlutxx: Now try adding `__slots__` to change the object memory layout. That can make even heap types incompatible.

Answer (score 19):

### When and how to do this

Changing the type ("casting") makes sense if you want to **add functionality** to an object created by some code you cannot change.

Assume some statement `obj = some_call_to_a_library()` gives you an object of class `A`. You want it to have additional functionality, say, `mymethod()`.
Then you could introduce a subclass `MyA` like this (Python 3 style):

```
class MyA(A):
    @classmethod
    def cast(cls, some_a: A):
        """Cast an A into a MyA."""
        assert isinstance(some_a, A)
        some_a.__class__ = cls  # now mymethod() is available
        assert isinstance(some_a, MyA)
        return some_a

    def mymethod(self):
        ...
```

and then write `obj = MyA.cast(some_call_to_a_library())`.
If `MyA` relies on additional attributes, `cast` (which is a factory method) should create them.

I just did something like this when I needed a version of `requests.Response` that could persist and retrieve responses to/from a file.

Comment: Nice. How safe is it to do this though? Is it always safe if `MyA` inherits from `A`?

Comment: @101: Depends on what you mean by 'safe'. In duck-typing thinking, it is sensible to do it if you do it sensibly (that is, if the addition `mymethod` is coherent given the overall program design, e.g., there should be no `mymethod` in `A`). If you want to call that safe, it's safe.

Answer (score 3):

I was asked this question by a colleague today.  He had a parent class that wanted to promote itself automatically to be one of its children based on an input at init time.  The following script worked as a proof of concept:

```
class ClassB(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__ = ClassA

    def blah2(self,t):
        print('I give you',t)
        return 'You are welcome'

class ClassA(ClassB):

   def blah(self, t):
       print('you gave me',t)
       return 'Thankyou'



a = ClassB()
print(type(a))
print(a.blah('sausage'))
print(a.blah2('cabbage'))
```

The result shows:

```
<class '__main__.ClassA'>
you gave me sausage
Thankyou
I give you cabbage
You are welcome
```

Which shows that both the parent and child functions are now available to `A`.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but here's a technique for safely extending the type of a python object.

```
def extendObject(obj):
    # Our extended type is explicitly derived from our existing type.
    class Extended(obj.__class__):
        # Whatever extensions you want to make.
        def someMethod(self):
            pass
    # Change the type of the object.
    obj.__class__ = Extended
    return obj
```

Comment: What are the benefits of this? Aren't you creating a new class (as in "type") for every object casted?

Comment: @ZaarHai the simple past and past participle of "cast" is "cast"