# how to print customized type() representation of python3 class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I made a simple Generic number class(actually function).

It returns the `NewClass` based input digits.

example) each line means the new class based on each digits.

```
def create_number_class(alphabet):
    class NewClass(object):
        pass
    return NewClass
```

almost code was deleted for your readability

```
BinClass = create_number_class("01")
DecimalClass = create_number_class("0123456789")
x = BinClass("100")
y = DecimalClass("3942")
```

in that case, the problem occurrs when print type(x)

when running code below, it

```
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
```

the output is same

```
<class '__main__.create_number_class.<locals>.NewClass'>
<class '__main__.create_number_class.<locals>.NewClass'>
```

I want to make them different. 
So, I changed the code as below, it doesn't work. 
So, I don't know how to to it. Always thank you all, lot of help to me.

```
def create_number_class(alphabet):
    class NewClass(object):
        pass
    NewClass.__name__ = alphabet # input data
    return NewClass
```

Comment: It’s generally not a good idea changing the `type` of an object, you should instead look into changing the `__str__` and/or `__repl__` of the object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing "type" of python objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404256/changing-type-of-python-objects)

Comment: Thank you all. it helps me a lot