# Casting? object to ansestor class?

Tags: python, casting

I want to extend the nltk.tree class i.e. :

```
 class XTree(Tree): 
    ......
```

What I want is to "cast" this return value to my XTree class,  because I don't have control over methods that return Tree objects, so that I can use the additional methods I have in XTree.

I know I can not cast in python, but how would I do what I want ? m'I missing something trivial

---

After some research I found that there is class method Tree.convert() which does exactly that :)

```
https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree
```

Anyway it is interesting if there is general solution to the question.

Comment: You want to downcast a `Tree` to an `XTree`?

Comment: You could try to just assign a new class to the object at run time: `object.__class__ = XTree` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404256/changing-the-class-of-a-python-object-casting