# wrap or decorate instance method of built-in class

Tags: python, class, instance, elementtree, monkeypatching

Is it possible to wrap a function of an instance of a built-in class, i.e. add functionality to an already created instance of a built-in class? As a concrete example, when parsing xml files using ElementTree, the `Element.find` method returns an Element or None, depending on if the Element can be found. However, I would like to raise a KeyError, every time an Element cannot be found, instead of returning None. Applying the solution below (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404256/changing-the-class-of-a-python-object-casting)), leads to an `TypeError: __class__ assignment only supported for heap types or ModuleType subclasses`. When trying to monkeypatch the function (not my preferred solution, as the KeyError raising Element shouldn't persist globally, but would be better than nothing), also produces a TypeError: `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'`. Is updating an instance with additional class functionality not possible, or am I completely over thinking the problem and there is a way simpler solution?

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, Optional, Text, Union
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

_str_argument_type = Union[str, Text]


class StrictElement(et.Element):
    @classmethod
    def from_element(cls, element: et.Element) -> "StrictElement":
        assert isinstance(element, et.Element)
        element.__class__ = cls
        assert isinstance(element, StrictElement)
        return element

    @staticmethod
    def find(
        path: _str_argument_type,
        namespaces: Optional[Dict[_str_argument_type, _str_argument_type]] = ...,
    ) -> "StrictElement":
        element = super().find(path, namespaces)
        if element is None:
            raise KeyError(f"unable to find element {path}")
        return StrictElement.from_element(element)

foo = et.parse("some_path") # some xml file with foo element but not foobar element
strict_foo = StrictElement.from_element(foo)
other_strict_foo = strict_foo.find("bar")
strict_foo.find("foobar") # should raise key error and not return None if element isn't found
```

Comment: I'd just create a free helper function along the lines of `def strict_find(element, match, namespaces=None): result = element.find(match, namespaces); if not result: raise KeyError(match); return result`. Not the prettiest API, but definitely the simplest.

Comment: That's the solution I'm going with right now, but my inner perfectionist is far from satisfied

Comment: I know how you feel :) You might be able to use a custom [`TreeBuilder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#treebuilder-objects) to create `StrictElement` objects directly while parsing.